# Email Notification in pm2-health

Tags: pm2

I am using pm2-health in NodeJs. It is sending email notification when there are run-time errors. But it is not sending email notifications when facing application level errors.

e.g. If hitting any URL and connection timeout is there, I am catching connection timeout in catch block of axios. Here I need to send email notification.

```js
axios({
        url: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_API,
        proxy: {
            protocol: 'http',
            host: 'hostname',
            port: 8080,
        },
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        data: qs.stringify(params),
        timeout: 5000, // 5 seconds timeout
    }).then(response => response.data)
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);

    }).catch(err => {
        //Here I want to send email notification
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like:

```
if ( $err ) {
    mail('email', 'PM2 Missing', implode("\n", $errored), 'From: email');
}
```